# Unfortunately My app has stopped

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-logcat

I am having trouble running my android application for debugging. This is my first time building an android application, so I am not familiar with this process. I am getting the following error message from LogCat

```
07-30 22:48:35.626: E/Trace(744): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  ... 11 more
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.wadi3mrad/com.example.wadi3mrad.biog}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1618)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.example.wadi3mrad.MainActivity.someFunction(MainActivity.java:55)
07-30 22:49:42.285: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  ... 14 more
```

**Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}
public void someFunction(View v)
{
   Intent myIntentd= new Intent();
     switch (v.getId()) // get id of Button clicked
     {
         case (R.id.music):
         myIntentd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 Albums.class);
        break;
         case (R.id.bio):
         myIntentd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 biog.class);
         break;
         case (R.id.face):
         myIntentd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 faceboom.class);
         break;
         case (R.id.info_but):
         myIntentd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 info.class);
         break;
     }
   startActivity(myIntentd);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Without any code, no one, except maybe Jon Skeet, can tell you where the problem is. But from looking at the logcat, you are trying to access an element of an `Array` that is more than what is in your `Array`

This line here

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
```

gives the exception saying you are trying to access index 3 but the size of your array is 3 so the highest possible index is 2 since an `Array` has a base of 0.

This line here (the first line after the exception which references your project) says which line in which `Activity` and what method that line is in

```
at com.example.wadi3mrad.MainActivity.addListenerOnButton(MainActivity.java:81)
```

Line 81 of `MainActivity` when adding a `listener` to a `Button`.

I realize this isn't an answer but you know what they say..."Teach a man to fish..."

**Edit**

Let's see how this goes. Since all of these buttons pretty much do one thing, a much easier and cleaner way to do this would be to declare on `onClick` function for all of these buttons in your xml then you don't need all of the listeners and the button array.

In your xml, for each button, add something like this line

```
android:onClick="someFunction"
```

then you just need one function in your Java and you don't need all of the other stuff. So your Java code would look like

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}

public void someFunction(View v)
{
   Intent myIntent = new Intent();
     switch (v.getId()) // get id of Button clicked
     {
         case (R.id.music):
         myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                Albums.class);
        break;
         case (R.id.bio):
         myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                biog.class);
         break;
         case (R.id.face):
         myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                faceboom.class);
         break;
         case (R.id.info_but):
         myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                info.class);
         break;
     }
   startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Where's your code? Please edit your OP and don't post it in a comment

Comment: am trying to put it but i cant i use this great site for first tim

Comment: Click "edit" underneath your post and paste the code in there. Then select all of the code and type "Ctrl + K"

Comment: am trying to put it but i cant i use this great site for first tim

Comment: @user2635244  You could read help, or just click the Edit button below your question.  I'm taking bets on `findViewById()` before `setContentView()`.

Comment: @Simon the exception is `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` not `NPE`

Comment: your post doesnot appera as acode ?????? whats wrong even thought here eroors all world erorrs

Comment: I'm sorry but that comment doesn't make sense. My post isn't code, rather a way to show you where the errors are in YOUR code. If you look directly below the [android] tags in your post you will see "edit". Click that and you can insert your code

Comment: "your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code " whats wrong???

Comment: Highlight the code andr press "Ctrl+K". This will format the code

Comment: @codeMagic http://www.4shared.com/file/lxP8Ws7Z/Albums.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/rRuVL9hH/MainActivity.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/qnsn-CFx/RichItem.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/oHUidqUi/RichItemAdapter.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/3qJYpXOB/Sounds.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/XXk_h7R5/Utilities.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/0kSYDZi_/biog.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/zPGzLGcr/faceboom.html
http://www.4shared.com/file/-CjqYkq0/info.html
http://www.4shared.com/office/rAQy4sY1/log.html

Comment: I'm trying but I'm not going to sign up so I can download one file. You figured out where the "edit" button is, correct? Click that and then click the button with the curly brackets {} in the toolbar then past only the code from `MainActivity` around line 81

Comment: Yay! Now which is line 81?

Comment: buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info_but);

Comment: this i think buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info_but);

Comment: I'm not sure why that is throwing that exception but check my answer. If you go through it carefully I think you will find that it will make your code easier and more readable.

Comment: Come on, man, I'm trying to help. Read from the **Edit** down carefully and follow that. I basically wrote all of the code that you need. Insert the line I put `android:onClick="someFunction"` in the `Button` tag of each button in xml. Then insert the function I wrote into your Java code. Remove your listener function and your Button array.

Comment: erorr at com.example.wadi3mrad.MainActivity.someFunction(MainActivity.java:57)
this line        startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: You can update your post with the new code and error. Otherwise, I can't know the problem